# Magento 2 - Language Package

Tags: magento2, language

I have created the langauage csv files using the following commands. And the translation is just working fine. Do I still need to create a language package as described in this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-pack)?

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o zh_hant_hk.csv -m .
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o zh_hans_cn.csv -m .

php bin/magento i18n:pack -d zh_hant_hk.csv . zh_Hant_HK
php bin/magento i18n:pack -d zh_hans_cn.csv . zh_Hans_CN
```